# php how to group data in table by days

Tags: php, laravel

I sitting in stuck and can't figure out how to solve this issue. I want to show table like this below monday to sunday with looping company names.

[image]

Table structure

**work_days**

- work_week_id (foreign-key work_week)
- day_id (foregin-key days)
- date
- completed

**worksheets**

- user_id (foregin-key user)
- office_id (foregin-key office)
- work_id (foregin-key works)
- work_day_id (foregin-key work_days)
- Hours
- Breaks

**WorksheetsController.php**

```
$workweek = WorkWeek::where([
                                ['user_id', $user->id],
                                ['completed', false]
                            ])->first();

$workdays = WorkDay::Where('work_week_id', $workweek->id)->with('worksheet', 'days')->get();

$days = Day::all();

$week = DateHandler::start_end_week_date($workweek->week);
        
return new WorkRapport($user, $workweek, $week, $days ,$workdays);
```

**rapport.blade.php (view)**

```
<table>

        
    <tr>
        @foreach ($days as $d) 

                @foreach ($workdays as $wd)                
                    @if ($d->id == $wd->day_id)                    
                        <td> {{ $d->day }}</td>                    
                    @endif                
                @endforeach                                   
            
        @endforeach      
    </tr>

    @foreach ($workdays as $wd)
        <tr>
            @if ($wd->day_id == 2)
                <td>2</td>
                <td>0</td>
            @elseif($wd->day_id == 3)
                <td>0</td>
                <td>3</td>
            @endif
        </tr>
    @endforeach

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the data then use groupBy() on the collection you get.

Example:

The groupBy method groups the collection's items by a given key:

```
$collection = collect([
   ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
   ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
   ['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
]);

$grouped = $collection->groupBy('account_id');

$grouped->toArray();

/*
     [
        'account-x10' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
        ],
        'account-x11' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
        ],
     ]
 */
```